# How to keep text inline with icon?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS. The text in `<li>` goes below the line of the icon. How can I fix it? I want to make text in the middle of line vertically. It happens when I add the `::before` with an icon.

[image]

```css
.benefits-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.benefits-element {
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 20;
}

.benefits-element:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.benefits-element:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.benefits-element::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('../assets/Icon\ -\ Okay.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <h2>Just relax <span>&</span> <br>Let us do the heavy lifting</h2>
  <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt.</p>
  <ul class="benefits-list">
    <li class="benefits-element">Initial Setup & Customizations</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Regular Updates</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Round The Clock Support</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button-main">Learn more</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below, so that the pseudo element aligns to the middle vertically along with the text.

```
.benefits-element::before {
  ...
  vertical-align: middle; /* default value is 'baseline' */
}
```

```css
.benefits-element {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.benefits-element::before {
  content: '';
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0V0zm0 0h24v24H0V0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M16.59 7.58L10 14.17l-3.59-3.58L5 12l5 5 8-8zM12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 / contain no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <h2>Just relax <span>&</span> <br>Let us do the heavy lifting</h2>
  <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt.</p>
  <ul class="benefits-list">
    <li class="benefits-element">Initial Setup & Customizations</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Regular Updates</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Round The Clock Support</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button-main">Learn more</button>
</section>
```

In addition, you don't have to use the pseudo element for the icon, just background image plus some left hand padding will do it.

```css
.benefits-element {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0V0zm0 0h24v24H0V0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M16.59 7.58L10 14.17l-3.59-3.58L5 12l5 5 8-8zM12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 / contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <h2>Just relax <span>&</span> <br>Let us do the heavy lifting</h2>
  <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt.</p>
  <ul class="benefits-list">
    <li class="benefits-element">Initial Setup & Customizations</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Regular Updates</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Round The Clock Support</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button-main">Learn more</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your li has a defined height.  This height is shorter than the font.  You can either make you li taller to accommodate or you can make the text smaller.

Make li taller (red outline for demonstration).

```
.benefits-element {
     margin: 10px 0;
     height: 30px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     box-sizing: borderbox;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jgoncalves/pen/ErGZMJ

```css
.benefits-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.benefits-element {
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: borderbox;
}

.benefits-element:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.benefits-element:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.benefits-element::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('../assets/Icon\ -\ Okay.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
  <h2>Just relax <span>&</span> <br>Let us do the heavy lifting</h2>
  <p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim. Donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt.</p>
  <ul class="benefits-list">
    <li class="benefits-element">Initial Setup & Customizations</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Regular Updates</li>
    <li class="benefits-element">Round The Clock Support</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button-main">
           Learn more
       </button>
</section>
```